# Passing an element with its applied styles using DOM Manipulation

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-manipulation

The goal here is to pass an element (one that is specifically being clicked on) using DOM Manipulation I wanted the svg element to appear with it's all it's applied styles. As of right now, the svg appears without any styling.

I'm thinking there's a way you can pass the clicked element with all of its stylings using `this.getAttribute` or `this.content` but those methods come back as undefined, which is why I currently use this.innerHtml (that at least gets clicked element and I can use DOM Manipulation with it).

added eventListeners to each svg element, paired with a function. `this.innerHTML` seemed to have worked (just the element and none of it's styling).

`svg.addEventListener('click', function)`

in the function below I used .content and getAttribute where it returned undefined

````
function () {
    var clickedSVG = this.innerHTML
    document.getElementById('container2').innerHTML = clickedSVG```
````

Comment: Has your issue been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply styles to an element on a click event you are going to want to add a class to the element using the classList property. Below is an example where you toggle an elements color on a click event.

First you create the HTML element you would like to toggle and give it an ID along with its default class:

```
<svg id="icon" class="not-clicked"></svg>
```

Then you create two CSS classes, one for the default stylings and another for the stylings to be applied on the click event:

```
.not-clicked {
      background-color: black;
    }    
.clicked {
      background-color: red;
    }
```

Then you create a javascript function where you define what you want to happen to your element on the click event, and then call that function with an event listener:

```
function changeColor(el) {
  if (el.classList.contains('not-clicked')) {
    el.classList.add('clicked');
    el.classList.remove('not-clicked')
  } else {
    el.classList.add('not-clicked');
    el.classList.remove('clicked')
  }
}

document.getElementById('icon').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        changeColor(e.target)
});
```